# Origins of the "next-next week" expression

Tags: english-to-japanese

I've heard more than a couple of times when  Japanese natives speaking English use "next-next week" expressesion to describe "the week after the next". I can't come up with an explanation where that strange expression comes from - after all the Japanese word 再来週 contains no repetition.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy question for a Japanese-speaker..

The reason that some Japanese say "next-next week" would be none other than the fact that when we explain what 「再来週{さらいしゅう}」 means to small kids, we often say that it means 「次{つぎ}の次の週{しゅう}」.

So, instead of trying to literally translate 「再来週」 kanji by kanji, which is not too easy, some people will end up literally translating 「次の次の週」 and come up with "next-next week".